# Sort a Map<String,Map<String,String>> in desc order dart

Tags: flutter, dart, data-structures

I have a Map of data.... I want to sort this map in desc order of message time. i.e. the message recieved in the newer date to come first.

Please help me out.

```
    Map<String,Map<String,String>> = 
                    {
                        "33": 
                            {
                                "id": "25766f01628f3d34b93a36a2301dffc9", 
                                "messageTime": "2023-07-02 20:42:09.994688", 
                                "messageContent": "Hi Hello", 
                                "read": "false"}
                        "35": 
                            {
                                "id": "b6617980ce90f637e68c3ebe8b9be745", 
                                "messageTime": "2023-07-10 20:42:09.994688", 
                                "messageContent": "Hi Hello How are you ?", 
                                "read": "false"
                            }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

void main() {
  Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = {
    "33": {
      "id": "25766f01628f3d34b93a36a2301dffc9",
      "messageTime": "2023-07-02 20:42:09.994688",
      "messageContent": "Hi Hello",
      "read": "false"
    },
    "35": {
      "id": "b6617980ce90f637e68c3ebe8b9be745",
      "messageTime": "2023-07-10 20:42:09.994688",
      "messageContent": "Hi Hello How are you ?",
      "read": "false"
    }
  };

  final sortedMap = Map.fromEntries(map.entries
      .sortedBy((element) => DateTime.parse(element.value['messageTime'] ?? ''))
      .reversed);

  print(sortedMap);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this and let me know

```
final sorted = Map.fromEntries(data.entries.toList()..sort((e1, e2) => e1.value['i']!.compareTo(e2.value['i']!)));
```

this  can help you to sort by value

```
void main() {  
     var data= 
                    {
                        "38": 
                            {
                                "id": "25766f01628f3d34b93a36a2301dffc9", 
                                "messageTime": "2023-07-02 20:42:09.994688", 
                                "messageContent": "Hi Hello", 
                                "read": "false",
                              "i":"3"
                           },
                        "35": 
                            {
                                "id": "b6617980ce90f637e68c3ebe8b9be745", 
                                "messageTime": "2025-07-10 20:42:09.994688", 
                                "messageContent": "Hi Hello How are you ?", 
                                "read": "false",
                              "i":"2"
                            }
                    };
  
  print(data);
  final sorted = Map.fromEntries(data.entries.toList()..sort((e1, e2) => e1.value['i']!.compareTo(e2.value['i']!)));

  print(sorted);

}
```